# VBA: Copy and paste cells in a email without losing formatting

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I want to be able to send out an email that contains cells from an Excel spreadsheet. Currently I have the following code that inserts the range I want into the email but the problem I am having is that it removes most of the formatting, e.g. the font changes and some of the conditional formatting is removed.

```
Sub EmailExtract()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim Location As String
Dim Individual As String
Dim rng As Range

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Worksheets("Contacts").Activate
Range("A2").Select
While ActiveCell <> ""

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Location = ActiveCell.Address
    Individual = ActiveCell.Value
    Worksheets("Individual Output 2").Activate
    Range("C2").Value = Individual

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M28").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If



    With objMail
            .To = "joe.bloggs@hotmail.com"
            .Subject = ""

            Dim Greeting As String
            If Time >= #12:00:00 PM# Then
                Greeting = "Afternoon ,"
            Else
                Greeting = "Morning,"
            End If



            .HTMLBODY = "<font face=Arial><p>" & "Good " + Greeting + "</p>"
            .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Please find below your " & MonthName((Month(Date)) - 1) & " Information." & "</p>"
            .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + RangetoHTML(rng)
            .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Kind Regards" & "</p>"
            .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Joe Bloggs" & "</p></font>"
            .Display
    End With
    Worksheets("Contacts").Activate
Wend

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

What I want is to be able to email an extract with the formatting applied, is it possible to do this? Maybe by pasting it as a picture into the email?

Comment: I used Ron De Bruin's function and made the swap suggested by Kemo and it worked all except for providing the cell widths. upon adding the following I got it looking in an email exactly as I wanted it: .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RangetoHTML` function on [Ron de Bruin's site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) has always worked fine for me.

Have you checked the `BodyFormat` property of the email? It might be defaulting to Rich Text.

Comment: this is what I used for the code, it don't think it shows how to keep the formats

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
```

with:

```
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=1
```

& delete these following 2 lines:

```
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
```